# Can not set Android Studio red dot break point

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I was able to set red dot break points in Android Studio with the same project. But after debugging a couple times a plugin crashed and now I can't set break points anymore. Even the "Run -> Toggle Line Breakpoint" is grayed out.

I did not get to see what plugin crashed.

How can I set break points?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what plugin crashed. It was smalidea. (https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/wiki/smalidea) I just had to import the plugin again.